# Android ListView inside ListFragment won't be clicked, onListItemClick() never reached

Tags: android, listview, android-fragments

The onListItemClick() method inside the class that extends ListFragment doesn't get called, and there isn't even a click animation when the list item is clicked.

Even when I set the TextViews to focusable="false" or its root element to android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants" it doesn't work.

The problem arises only with a CustomAdapter, when I use the default ArrayAdapter with the default android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1 there is no problem. Also, I can set listView.setOnItemClickListener(...) and the list will get clicked at the correct position (but without click animation).

Here is the relevant code:

```
    public class MyListFragment extends ListFragment {

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_list, container, false);
        }

        @Override
        public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    //        String[] strings = {"one", "two", "three", "four"};
    //        ArrayList stringsList = new ArrayList(Arrays.asList(strings));
    //        ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter(getContext(),android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,stringsList);

            ArrayList items = new ArrayList();
            for (int i = 1; i < 20; i++) {
                items.add(new Item("Sample Item " + i));
            }

            CustomAdapter adapter = new CustomAdapter(getContext(), items);
            setListAdapter(adapter);
            super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        }

        @Override
        public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
            Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Toast", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
```

```
    import android.content.Context;
    import android.database.DataSetObserver;
    import android.view.LayoutInflater;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.ViewGroup;
    import android.widget.ImageView;
    import android.widget.ListAdapter;
    import android.widget.TextView;

    import java.util.ArrayList;

        public class CustomAdapter implements ListAdapter {

            Context context;
            ArrayList items;

            public CustomAdapter(Context context, ArrayList items) {
                this.context = context;
                this.items = items;
            }

            @Override
            public void registerDataSetObserver(DataSetObserver observer) {

            }

            @Override
            public void unregisterDataSetObserver(DataSetObserver observer) {

            }

            @Override
            public int getCount() {
                return items.size();
            }

            @Override
            public Item getItem(int position) {
                return items.get(position);
            }

            @Override
            public long getItemId(int position) {
                return 0;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean hasStableIds() {
                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
                Holder holder;
                LayoutInflater layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);

                if (convertView == null) {
                    holder = new Holder();
                    convertView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.item_row, null);
                    holder.title = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.title_textView);
                    holder.description = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.description_textView);
                    convertView.setTag(holder);
                } else {
                    holder = (Holder) convertView.getTag();
                }
                holder.title.setText(getItem(position).getTitle());
                holder.description.setText(getItem(position).getDescription());

                return convertView;
            }

            @Override
            public int getItemViewType(int position) {
                return 0;
            }

            @Override
            public int getViewTypeCount() {
                return 1;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean isEmpty() {
                return items.isEmpty();
            }

            @Override
            public boolean areAllItemsEnabled() {
                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean isEnabled(int position) {
                return false;
            }

            class Holder {
                TextView title, description;
            }
        }
```

```
        public class Item {
            private String title = "test";
            private String description = "test description";

            public Item(String title) {
                this.title = title;
            }

            public String getTitle() {
                return title;
            }

            public String getDescription() {
                return description;
            }


            @Override
            public String toString() {
                return getTitle();
            }
        }
```

```
    import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
    import android.os.Bundle;


    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        }


    }
```

I'm not able to post the xml, but it is a very simple TextView inside the item_row.xml, a ListView with the android:list id for the fragment_list.xml, and the single fragment for the activity_main.xml.

Here is the minimal failing example to download: https://github.com/ronenlh/ListFragment

Thank you.

---

Edit: **I found the solution.** I implemented ListAdapter for the adapter, but I had to extend any one of two classes that android provides that implements ListAdapter for me. SimpleAdapter for static data (Maps), and SimpleCursorAdapter for Cursor query results.

Comment: The problem could in your xml item if the TextViews or ImageViews or whatever occupy the hole space reserved for each item

Comment: @manolodewin It's an horizonal LinearLayout with match_parent both ways, then a square ImageView of 70dp, adjacent a vertical LinearLayout with two wrap_content TextViews.

Comment: try to replace that for a simple textview. That works now?

Comment: @manolodewin now the row is just a textview with height, width, id and schemas. Still no click. Here is the project with the latest version of Gradle: https://github.com/ronenlh/ListFragment

Comment: I found the solution. I implemented ListAdapter for the adapter, but I had to use (extend) any one of two classes that android provides that implements ListAdapter for me. SimpleAdapter for static data (Maps), and SimpleCursorAdapter for Cursor query results. Thanks @manolodewin.